# Returning multiple values from an Oracle 12c function

Tags: sql, plsql, stored-functions, oracle12c

I am writing a function in Oracle 12c (and it has to be a function) that should return 3 values, `order_line.o_id`, a variable `total` that I create in the function, and a `discounted_amount` variable that I create in the function.

I have gotten my function to create the discounted_amount variable and return it but I am not sure how to get it to return these other two values.

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION DiscountsReport (input_o_id IN REAL) 
RETURN REAL 
IS 
  output_o_id      NUMBER; 
  total            REAL; 
  discounted_total REAL; 
  percent          REAL; 
BEGIN 
    output_o_id := input_o_id; 

    SELECT SUM(o.ol_quantity * o.ol_price) 
    INTO   total 
    FROM   order_line o 
    WHERE  o.o_id = input_o_id; 

    IF total > 100 THEN 
      percent := 0.1; 
    ELSIF total > 200 THEN 
      percent := 0.2; 
    ELSE 
      percent := 0.0; 
    END IF; 

    discounted_total := ( total * ( 1 - percent ) ); 

    RETURN discounted_total; 
END;
```

Comment: A function can only return one thing.  You could create an object (or a record type) that includes three columns and return an instance of that object or record.  Or you could declare the function to have multiple `OUT` parameters but that seems architecturally quite a poor choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE new_type AS OBJECT(v1 type1, v2 type2, v3 type3);
```

and use it after `RETURN` (call the result `output` - its type is `new_type`).

You can access those values using:

```
output.v1
output.v2
output.v3
```

Comment: When I tried using the create of replace statement you mentioned (except with the proper types instead of type1) I got an error "Error(5,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" "

Comment: Add `/` after/before that line and see what happens...(on a new line)

Comment: Ah... that's embarassing. Yup, that was it lol. How do I then create an instance of that type to get as output from the function when I run it

Comment: Something like this: `RETURN new_type`, in `IS`: `output new_type`, between BEGIN and END: `output.v1/2/3 := x1/2/3 `and `RETURN output`

Comment: Okay, cool. I am testing the function, but I can't figure out how to print an instance of new_type. Is there some special way that is done?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but...
`dbms_output.put_line(output.v1)`, `dbms_output.put_line(output.v2)`, `dbms_output.put_line(output.v3)` should work.